# How do you run the `Job` in the spring batch in a production environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I implemented now with `spring batch` to manage dormant account. The following problems occurred while using the `spring batch`.

[Spring Batch When I run using joblauncher, I think the job is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73450739/spring-batch-when-i-run-using-joblauncher-i-think-the-job-is-not-running)

The rough content of the article is that the method with `@Bean` cannot be executed because it is managed as a single tone in the `spring`.

I wanted to run `Job` somehow using the `@Scheduled` and solved it with the following solution.

> 1. Replace the `@Configuration` in the batch class I created with `@Component`.
> 2. Erase all `@Bean` on the `Job`, `Step`, `Reader`, `Processor`, and `Writer`.

After doing so, `Job` worked as I wanted and got a log.

I solved the problem, but there was another problem.

In a lot of example, even spring official documents attached `@Bean` at all of Job.

Furthermore, it seemed that `JobParameter` could not be used without `@Bean` attached. (When I tried to use the `JobParameter`, the initial value was `null`.)

I'm going to ask you a real question now.

`Spring Batch` will also be used in the field. And it's expected to put `@Bean`, as it says in the official document. So, how do you run a Job in the field?

Please let me know where I need to fix in my code.

```
package com.capston.chatting.service.scheduler;

import com.capston.chatting.config.batch.InactiveMemberJob;
import com.capston.chatting.entity.Member;
import com.capston.chatting.enums.MemberStatus;
import com.capston.chatting.repository.MemberRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.batch.core.*;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ScheduleService {

    private final InactiveMemberJob config;
    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;
    private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    //test

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * *")
    public void runInactiveMemberScheduler() {
        try {
            jobLauncher.run(
                    config.inactiveMemberJob(), new JobParametersBuilder(jobExplorer)
                            .getNextJobParameters(config.inactiveMemberJob())
                            .addString("requestDate", LocalDateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 16))
                            .addString("test", "Test")
                            .toJobParameters()
            );
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.capston.chatting.config.batch;

import com.capston.chatting.entity.Member;
import com.capston.chatting.enums.MemberStatus;
import com.capston.chatting.repository.MemberRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class InactiveMemberJob {

    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    public Job inactiveMemberJob() {
        log.info("InactiveMemberJob execution");
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("inactiveMemberJob")
                .start(inactiveJobStep())
                .preventRestart()
                .incrementer(new UniqueRunIdIncrementer())
                .build();
    }

    public Step inactiveJobStep() {
        log.info("InactiveMemberStep execution");
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("inactiveMemberStep")
                .<Member, Member>chunk(10)
                .reader(inactiveMemberReader(null))
                .processor(inactiveMemberProcessor())
                .writer(inactiveMemberWriter())
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .build();
    }

    @StepScope
    public ListItemReader<Member> inactiveMemberReader(@Value("#{jobparameters[test]}") String test) {
        log.info("InactiveMemberReader execution");
        log.info("JobParameters : {}", test);

        List<Member> oldMembers = memberRepository
                .findByUpdateDateBeforeAndStatusEquals(LocalDateTime.now().minusYears(1), MemberStatus.ACTIVE);

        return new ListItemReader<>(oldMembers);
    }

    public ItemProcessor<Member, Member> inactiveMemberProcessor() {
        log.info("test");
        ItemProcessor<Member, Member> memberItemProcessor = (member) -> {
            log.info("InactiveMemberProcessor execution");
            return member.setInactive();
        };
        return memberItemProcessor;
//        return new ItemProcessor<Member, Member>() {
//            @Override
//            public Member process(Member member) throws Exception {
//                log.info("InactiveMemberProcessor execution");
//                return member.setInactive();
//            }
//        };
//        return member -> {
//            log.info("InactiveMemberProcessor execution");
//            return member.setInactive();
//        };
    }

    public ItemWriter<Member> inactiveMemberWriter() {
        log.info("InactiveMemberWriter execution");
        return ((List<? extends Member> members) -> {
            memberRepository.saveAll(members);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you annotate a method with `@Bean`, you are asking the Spring container to call that method to create an instance of a the method's return type with the indicated scope. The default scope is Application scope, which is one instance for the application, also known as singleton. The annotation `@StepScope` has no meaning on a method that is not also annotated as `@Bean`. It tells the container to provide one instance of the class for the current `Step` -- not just one for the application. This sets a context in which job parameters make sense, since the `Step` is within the context of the `Job` for which those parameters are defined. The spring property referenced by the `@Value` annotation will be evaluated by the Spring container when it creates the bean, which it will do only if the method is annotated with `@Bean` (or a class annotated with `@Component` or an extension of that annotation). This is why, when `inactiveMemberReader(null)` is called to define the reader in your `Step`, the job parameter "test" has a null value. Without the `@Bean` annotation telling the Spring container to create it for the `Step`, it is just a plain method being passed null as the value for the `test` String argument.

Comment: Opps... I forgot erase that annotation and `@Value`. Above the code is not related with this annotation. I little bit know what you're saying. But thanks to you, I learned more. Thank you for your answer, but it's not the answer to the question I want, so I can't adopt it

Comment: That's the correct answer IMO. It does not make sense to use `@StepScope` without a `@Bean`. Moreover, your `InactiveMemberJob` class should be annotated with `@Configuration` in which you define your Spring Batch beans (at least a `Job` bean, unless you use a scoped component, which also would have to be declared as a bean). Once that in place, the `Job` bean can then be injected elsewhere (a web controller, a scheduled method, etc) to be executed when needed.

Comment: Do you mean that if I register Job as `@Bean`, I can use JobLauncher as controller or scheduler? However, when I registered Job as `@Bean` and used it, only the log message that Job and Step were executed appears, and the log message that I wrote in Reader, Processor, and Writer does not appear. The Reader, Processor, and Writer are not working, so the business logic in method is not working. And in the question linked to the question, I heard the answer. @Bean The registered method is managed in a single tone, so it cannot be executed in any way other than running when the application starts.