# While taking Bean out of ApplicationContext, there was an error that the MemberRepository did not have an error occurred

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to declare `ApplicationContext` and take out `Bean` using getBean.

But I got this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inactiveMemberJobConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.capston.chatting.repository.MemberRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.capston.chatting.repository.MemberRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I expect that I have already used @Repository to register the MemberRepository as an bean

However, the error log shows that there is no MemberRepository.

I don't understant where is wrong

Below is my code.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(InactiveMemberJobConfig.class);
Job inactiveMemberJob = (Job) ac.getBean("inactiveMemberJob");
```

```
@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<Member, Long> {

    @Query("select m from Member m where m.loginId = :loginId")
    Member findMemberByLoginId(@Param("loginId") String loginId);

    List<Member> findByUpdateDateBeforeAndStatusEquals(LocalDateTime localDateTime, MemberStatus status);
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class InactiveMemberJobConfig {

    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Try this `@Autowired private final MemberRepository memberRepository;`

Comment: @maddy23285 Thank you for your answer. I tried as you said, but the error still appears. And the `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, as far as I know, makes a constructor for the `final keyword` and puts `@Autowired` on it, so it doesn't seem right to do as you say.

Answer (score 0):

For a bean to be known to an application context it needs to be registered. That can happen e.g. through component scanning which detects the annotation on the class and registers it as a bean.

When you do `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()` you created a new application context. This application context did not do any component scanning yet. Furthermore, within this constructor it tries to find the bean dependencies of the class you pass as constructor parameter. But since no component scanning has taking place yet it cannot find it.

You need to create your application context with a class that has no bean dependencies yet. And then register your beans, e.g. through executing the component scan on you application context.

See example below:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);
ac.scan(MyConfig.class.getPackageName());
InactiveMemberJobConfig inactiveMemberJob = (InactiveMemberJobConfig) ac.getBean(InactiveMemberJobConfig.class);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your explanation helped me a lot to understand `ApplicationContext`. But unfortunately, it didn't help me solve my problem. Because section of occured error in my case is that line declaring `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`. So, I changed it based on what you told me, but I think I get the same error. `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(InactiveMemberJobConfig.class).scan(InactiveMemberJobConfig.class.getPackageName());` And I didn't explain it in the question, but my project works well, but I got an error when I called the method with the code.

Comment: Is it okay to understand that my project is running normally and it becomes `ComponentScan`? Then it's going to get even weirder, but when I open ApplicationContext, there's no Bean, the MemberRepository, right?

Comment: You are creating a NEW application context by calling `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()`. So it really doesn't matter if you projects works normally and usually does component scanning. Your new application context cannot be created because you initialize it with `InactiveMemberJobConfig` and it can't find the MemberRepository Bean yet at that point.

Comment: I totally understand. Then, is there a way to proceed with `ComponentScan` before the new `ApplicationContext` is initialized? Or is there something to prevent the error from appearing when initializing?

Comment: Do it like in my example. Create a Config class without bean dependencies and use that for initialization of the application context. Afterwards call `ac.scan()`. Alternatively, you might want rethink the reason why you need to create a new application context in the first place. This is not really how spring is meant to be used I would say.

Comment: Oh, I'll explain about that part. I am currently working on a Toy project to manage dormant members using `Spring Batch`. However, when I finished making the `Job` and ran it using `JobLauncher`, I couldn't get the movement I wanted. I wanted to execute methods registered as `@Bean`. However, according to the link below, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73450739/spring-batch-when-i-run-using-joblauncher-i-think-the-job-is-not-running` the method registered as `@Bean` was answered that it could no longer be executed

Comment: because it was only executed at the time the application was started and managed as a single tone. On a Korean community site I know, I posted a question about how to use `JobLauncher` in the real field, and I received an answer that I would take out Job using getBean in `ApplicationContext` and run it as `JobLauncher`. I am experimenting with that answer.

Comment: I don't think you need to execute that method again. The Bean was created on startup and can now be autowired where you need it. So in you scheduler you can Autowire the Job and then pass it into the JobLauncher to execute it.

Comment: It's not that I didn't think about it. `@Bean` I put the registered Job in the `JobLauncher` and turned it around, but the action I wanted didn't work. I wanted to execute the method itself with `@Bean` attached.  However, after hearing what you said, I thought that it was the same thing as taking `Bean` out of `Application Context` with `getBean` or being injected with `Autowired`. So I wanted to know how to run `JobLauncher` in the field, so I posted a question on the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73480999/how-do-you-run-the-job-in-the-spring-batch-in-a-production-environment